# How to render blender by using Google Cloud GPU

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

Is it feasible to do that? Are there any documentations available or any tutorial for reference?

thanks!

Comment: tried   a very simple blender scene on both my mac/ win and GCP instance w/ Tesla V100 GPU by using command line, ie. `blender -b sample.blend -o //result_ -F PNG a`. Its speed looks not faster than my mac/win. Is anything wrong?

Comment: Haven't tried it personally yet but have a look at - 1- https://medium.com/google-cloud/leveraging-google-compute-engine-for-low-cost-gpu-rendering-and-other-fun-exercises-in-patience-bf621cd6b0ae 2 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6FzdMZbvEo (Rendering Blender Projects on Google Cloud Compute Engine)